# Using Turbo Frames How Can I Reload The Whole Page If The Form Submited Succeeded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo-frames

I have

- 1: a link in a turbo frame which loads a form into the same frame. Working Well
- 2: the form if it is not valid then should only update itself by marking the missing fields with errrors. Working Well
- 3: in case the form submission is successfull, I should redirect, that is not working well, because it is rendering the result of the redirect in `as TURBO_STREAM`, somehow I should break out to top in that case.

Basically this is the code:

```
- list_of_projects...
= turbo_frame_tag 'new_project'
  = link_to "New Project", new_project_path
```

then in `views/projects/new.html.slim` I have:

```
= turbo_frame_tag 'new_project' do
  = simple_form_for @project_form, url: projects_path do |form|
...
```

Then in the controller:

```
  def create
    @project_form = ProjectForm.new project_params
    if @project_form.valid?
      command_bus.(Conversations::Commands::CreateProject.new(id: SecureRandom.uuid,
                                                          title: @project_form.title))

      # should redirect without AS Turbo
      redirect_to projects_url
```

Any ideas how to do it in a reusable manner?

Answer (score 7):

A little foreword. If you just need to get out of the frame see other answers, or read the [docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes): `data-turbo-frame` attribute is what you need. This answer is when you want to **conditionally** get out of the frame based on what happens during form submission.

---

This is "new" in *Turbo* [v7.3.0](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/releases/tag/v7.3.0)  (*turbo-rails* [v1.4.0](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/releases/tag/v1.4.0)), redirect behavior when frame is missing is reverted to the original way of forever staying in a frame.

There is a `turbo:frame-missing` event emitted so that you could customize this behavior:

> **`turbo:frame-missing`** - fires when the response to a `<turbo-frame>`
> element request does not contain a matching `<turbo-frame>` element.
> By default, Turbo writes an informational message into the frame and
> throws an exception. Cancel this event to override this handling. You
> can access the `Response` instance with `event.detail.response`, and
> perform a visit by calling `event.detail.visit(...)`
> *https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events*

Like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("turbo:frame-missing", (event) => {
  const { detail: { response, visit } } = event;
  event.preventDefault();
  visit(response.url);
});
```

While this works, it does one more request to the server, which is what used to happen way back.

If you want to just display the redirected response, you can `visit` the `response`:

```js
document.addEventListener("turbo:frame-missing", (event) => {
  const { detail: { response, visit } } = event;
  event.preventDefault();
  visit(response); // you have to render your "application" layout for this
});
```

Turbo frame requests used to render without a layout, they now [render](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.4.0/app/controllers/turbo/frames/frame_request.rb#L24) within a tiny [layout](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.4.0/app/views/layouts/turbo_rails/frame.html.erb). `response` has to be a full page response to be visitable, otherwise, *turbo* will refresh the page, which makes it even worse. This would fix it:

```rb
def show
  render layout: "application"
end
```

---

Custom turbo stream redirect solution:

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/75750578/207090*

I think it's simpler than the solution below.

---

### Set a custom header

This lets you choose on the front end if and when you want to break out of the frame.

Set a data attribute with a controller action name, like `data-missing="controller_action"` *(or any other trigger you need, like, controller name as well)*:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag "form_frame", data: { missing: "show" } do %>
#                                                   ^
# this is where missing frame is expected, it's not strictly 
# necessary, but it's where "application" layout is required
```

This was more of a "i wonder if that would work" type of a solution, just make sure you need it:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

addEventListener("turbo:before-fetch-request", (event) => {
  const headers = event.detail.fetchOptions.headers;
  // find "#form_frame[data-missing]"
  const frame = document.querySelector(`#${headers["Turbo-Frame"]}[data-missing]`);
  if (frame) {
    // if frame is marked with `data-missing` attribute, send it with request
    headers["X-Turbo-Frame-Missing"] = frame.dataset.missing;
  }
});

addEventListener("turbo:frame-missing", (event) => {
  const { detail: { response, visit } } = event;
  if (response.headers.get("X-Turbo-Frame-Missing")) {
    // if response has "frame missing" header it can be rendered
    // because we'll make sure it's rendered with a full layout
    event.preventDefault();
    visit(response);
  }
});
```

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout -> {
    if turbo_frame_request?
      # check if we are in an action where a missing frame is
      # if you're jumping between controllers, you might need to
      # have controller name in this header as well
      if request.headers["X-Turbo-Frame-Missing"] == action_name
        # let `turbo:frame-missing` response handler know it's ok to render it
        headers["X-Turbo-Frame-Missing"] = true
        # because it's a full page that can be displayed
        "application"
      else
        "turbo_rails/frame"
      end
    end
  }
end
```

---

*[https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#breaking-out-from-a-frame](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#%E2%80%9Cbreaking-out%E2%80%9D-from-a-frame)*

*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/863*

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the kind of experience you are trying to achieve, but it seems to me that the easiest way to make this work is to specify `_top` as the turbo frame when submitting the form. It can be set on the button or the form.

```
= turbo_frame_tag 'new_project' do
  = simple_form_for @project_form, url: projects_path do |form|
    ...
    form.button :submit, "Save", data: {turbo_frame: "_top"}
```

Then in your controller, do the redirect as normal.