# Getting a Turbo Frame Error of "Content Missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails, turbo-frames

I'm trying to use turbo_frame_tag in my Rails application to manage some tasks. I created a scaffold for my tasks.

I wrapped the page I want to use inside of a turbo frame tag as below:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "modal" do %>

      <h1>New task</h1>
      <%= render "form", task: @task %>
      <br>
      <div>
        <%# <%= link_to "Back to tasks", tasks_path %> %>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", data: {
          controller: "modals",
          action: "modals#close"
        }, class: "cancel-button" %>
      </div>

<% end %>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UbS1.png)

In my home page index.html.erb file I added data to my Add button with the same tag:

```
<%= link_to "Add", new_task_path, data: { turbo_frame: "modal" }, class: "btn btn-secondary", remote: true %>
```

The modal is working correctly. It is opened when I click the Add button on my home page. When I try to submit my action to create a new task, I see on my terminal 200 Response and the new task is added to my database.

But (also) I get the "Content Missing" text information on my home page. The page isn't reloaded. In the developer browser I get this error:

```
turbo.es2017-esm.js:3650 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The response (200) did not contain the expected \<turbo-frame id="modal"\> and will be ignored. To perform a full page visit instead, set turbo-visit-control to reload.
at c.delegateConstructor.throwFrameMissingError (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3650:15)
at c.delegateConstructor.handleFrameMissingFromResponse (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3646:14)
at c.delegateConstructor.loadFrameResponse (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3567:18)
at async c.delegateConstructor.loadResponse (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3441:34)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUUH2.png)

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails and everything is new for me. I would be grateful for any help and information if anyone had such a problem and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 13):

This behavior is introduced and documented in this [PR](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/863). Note that the hotwire documentation has been updated with a [recommended solution](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#%E2%80%9Cbreaking-out%E2%80%9D-from-a-frame).

You can specify that a page should redirect instead of rendering the `Content Missing` error by adding a [turbo visit control tag] (https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes#meta-tags).

To make it easier, you can utilize a turbo helper method.

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->

<meta name="turbo-visit-control" content="reload">

<!-- or -->

<%= turbo_page_requires_reload %>
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly add a `data: {turbo_frame: "_top"}` to specify that a link should break out of the turbo_frame.

Comment: `data: {turbo_frame: "_top"}` is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When you redirect after the form submission, there is no `<turbo-frame>` with the same id, so you get frame missing error. For some details and my first attempt at a reusable solution:

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/75704489/207090*

I don't want to post a duplicate answer, but I'll mention that there is a `turbo:frame-missing` event, that you can listen for and handle the error:

```js
document.addEventListener("turbo:frame-missing", (event) => {
  const { detail: { response, visit } } = event;
  event.preventDefault();
  visit(response.url);
});
```

One caveat with doing a simple `visit(response.url)` is that it will be the second request to that url (first one is from the redirect).

The ideal place to handle this would be at the redirect response, because that's where you'd know if form submission was successful or not and send redirect as a regular `Turbo.visit` outside of the frame. Which you can do by sending some javascript in a *turbo_stream*:

```rb
render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(
  request.headers["Turbo-Frame"],
  helpers.javascript_tag(
    "Turbo.visit('#{model_url(@model)}')",
    data: {turbo_temporary: true} # one time only; don't cache it
  )
)
```

To make it a bit prettier, do the same thing but in a custom turbo stream action.

---

### Make a custom *turbo_stream.redirect* action

Tag for "redirect" action would look like this:

```html
<turbo-stream action="redirect" target="/url"></turbo-stream>
```

Add new action to *Turbo* to handle it on the front end:
*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#custom-actions*

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails";

Turbo.StreamActions.redirect = function () {
  Turbo.visit(this.target);
};

// or using event listener

document.addEventListener("turbo:before-stream-render", (event) => {
  const fallbackToDefaultActions = event.detail.render;
  event.detail.render = function (streamElement) {
    if (streamElement.action == "redirect") {
      Turbo.visit(streamElement.target);
    } else {
      fallbackToDefaultActions(streamElement);
    }
  };
});
```

Use generic `action` method to render it in a controller or in a template:

```rb
turbo_stream.action(:redirect, model_url(@model))
```

You can also add `redirect` method to `turbo_stream` helper:

```rb
# config/initializers/stream_actions.rb

module CustomTurboStreamActions
  # turbo_stream.redirect(model_url(@model))
  def redirect url
    action(:redirect, url)
  end
end
Turbo::Streams::TagBuilder.include(CustomTurboStreamActions)
```

Example of how to get out of the frame:

```rb
# app/controllers/*_controller.rb

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @model.update(model_params)
      format.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.redirect(model_url(@model)) 
      end
      format.html { redirect_to model_url(@model), notice: "Updated." }
    else
      format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One thing I don't quite understand... Won't the turbo frame request itself be a `format.html` request,  not a `format.turbo_stream` request? That's what I think I'm seeing... I want to break out of the turbo-frame with a redirect. Can I use this (elegant) approach to extending turbo with a custom action in that scenario?

Comment: @gap when you submit the form it should be a `turbo_stream` request. if you just need to click out of the frame add `data-turbo-frame="_top"` to the link.

Comment: I only know I need to break out based on server-side decisions (error case/ redirect). The client doesn't know or presume that

Comment: @gap actually you should be able to respond to html turbo_frame requests with turbo_stream. if it doesn't work just post another question with your setup.

Comment: This should be added to the turbo-rails gem.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message after updating from `turbo-rails` `1.3.3` to `1.4.0`. It looks like this is a breaking change in `1.4.0`. It happens because the current version of `turbo-rails` assumes that all actions lead to updates inside the `turbo-frame`. Of course that's not always the case. Especially not if the `turbo-frame`'s content is a search result list. If you want that links inside the `turbo-frame` update the whole page, then you need to add `target="_top"` to the `turbo-frame` tag. Here a complete example:

```
<turbo-frame id="supplier_contracts" data-turbo-action="advance" target="_top" >
```

That solved the problem for me.